# Uncaught Error: #90211 ExtensionName Error - Node.JS, Heroku, JavaScript App using FusionCharts

Tags: javascript, heroku, fusioncharts

After updating my NPM packages, this application stopped working and started throwing the following errors:

```
**Error Message #1**
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at o (fusioncharts.js:13)
    at o.t (fusioncharts.js:13)

**Error Message #2**
Uncaught Error: #90211 ExtensionName Error >> A FusionCharts extension must have a getName API or a name property.
at o (fusioncharts.js:13)
at Function.i (fusioncharts.js:13)
at Function.e.addDep (fusioncharts.js:13)
at fusioncharts.js:13
```

The Error #1 appears once, and Error #2 happens about 30x, until it crashes the app.

**Things I tried**

1. Lots of googling about these errors, very little information came up; searched SO and found nothing about these specific errors.
2. I thought the errors might mean the CDN for FusionCharts was corrupted, so I replaced the CDN and refreshed (tried several options); no change.
3. I also considered that a global variable may be messing something up, but I double-checked and all of my required dependencies are in the package.json.
4. I thought it might be related to package managers, so I tried running "NPM install" and "Yarn install" to refresh packages. Nothing.

Does anyone have any ideas about these errors? Or other things I can try?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the FusionCharts minified file you're importing?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but here is the CDN I'm using (it's in the index.html): 
https://cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusioncharts/latest/fusioncharts.js

Comment: I think it would be quite helpful to try with an unminified library to see where is the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

This was a package management issue. I was using NPM and Yarn together (known to be risky), and I accidentally used "npm install" to refresh the packages instead of "yarn install". This scrambled the yarn tree for my local environment, creating dependency gaps. I tried "yarn install", but by then it was too late (detailed explanation [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/yarn-vs-npm/))

To fix this, you need to reset your local environment.

Steps I took to resolution:

```
1. Delete node & yarn and local repository

2. Reinstall node & yarn and download repo

3. Run "yarn install" (builds the dependency tree)

4. Run "yarn start" or "yarn dev"
```

I'm very relieved this worked. I hope this is helpful, please comment for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

For others that run into this issue, it can also be a matter of mismatch fusioncharts versions between what you have installed with node and what is in the index.html of your project.

```
<script
   type="text/javascript"
   src="https://cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusioncharts/3.18.0/fusioncharts.js"
></script>
```

The version defined here (`3.18.0`) must match what is installed via node (`fusioncharts@3.18.0`).

This was the case when using both Fusiontime & Fusioncharts Suites in an angular(v12.2) project.